# ExpressionEngine 404 Not found - /index.php/products was not found

Tags: htaccess, 404

I have just begun working with ExpressionEngine. The production site is working just fine and I wanted to create a local version for dev purposes.

I am receiving 404 not found errors on my localhost pages such as localhost:8888/example.com/products or localhost:8888/example.com/aboutus, but the index or home page comes up just fine - localhost:8888/example.com/

I have followed the steps for migration from this link - http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html

1) Downloaded flat files via ftp
2) Used a backup .sql to load the local mysql
3) Able to login to system - localhost:8888/dev.example.com/system - all usernames & passwords work
4) Setup all the URLs within Admin> General Configuration - so on and so forth

I was able to fix my template synch issue by going into the Design> Templates> Global Preferences and change the path to the templates' path on my computer - they were still set to the template’s path in production.

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.example.com/templates

Both the localhost:8888/example.com/system and the initial index page - localhost:8888/example.com/ - function exactly as they would be expected to do.

I have created an htaccess file and placed it within /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.example.com/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I am still receiving a 404 not found error whenever I try to go to localhost:8888/example.com/products then it thinks that /index.php/products was not found, why does it not say products/index.php?

BTW, is the path to the templates supposed to be this:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.genesistoday.com/templates

or this:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dev.genesistoday.com/templates/default_site/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running from `localhost:8888`, then locally you are essentially running these sites from subdirectories. So the .htaccess you are using (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`) is sending requests to `http://localhost:8888/index.php`.

Try the [second exception](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html#exceptions) from the user guide:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Notice there is no `/` in front of the index.php. You will also want to remove the `RewriteBase /` otherwise it will prepend that to your rules, which you don't want in this case.

Comment: Yes, I followed your advice and removed the "/" character, restarted Apache/MySQL and it is still doing the same thing

Comment: Try removing the RewriteBase as well, I'd expect that's prepending the `/` to all of your rules.

Comment: That was it. It worked. Thank you so much Derek

Comment: Okay, great. I updated the answer so it's a complete solution. Don't forget to mark it as answered so it's easier for others to find later.